# monitor shell script's log file via web interface

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, logging

I'm shell scripts to extract data from the database transfom and append, this script have a lot of echo statements printed as logs,

How can i access/moniter these logs via a web interface,any html/javascript/ajax/open source tools

Thank you

Jeyaprakash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to parse your log files, so they should be in a consistent format. I suppose that will not be necessary if you simply wish to display the log files. If there is parsing overhead, you probably want to store the parsed data as log_entries in your database so that you can view them quickly. From there, it's just a matter of sending the data from your server to your web browser. A simple HTML page can then just refresh the log view (be it the log file or a tabular representation of your log data) at a set interval, or when a user clicks some button.

The log view will likely be written in some server-side language, unless you have decided to store your log files in a static directory served by your web server. Popular languages for this include PHP, Python, Ruby, and Perl. If you are at all familiar with the language, Perl may be ideal for this task, as it excels at reading logs. It will make the most sense for you to send the data to the browser serialized, as JSON or XML. JSON is very popular these days and is easy to work with in JavaScript, as you turn the JSON string into a JavaScript object via JSON.parse(str).

You may find a UI library helpful for presenting the log data attractively. Often it is best to write your own widgets for simple applications like this one, but it can be time consuming, especially if you are new to the process. Popular UI libraries include jQuery UI, Sencha (formerly ExtJS), and the Closure Library's UI (goog.ui) package.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I would give a try.